# Naive Bayes - Output

Tags: r

I've been working a task concerning Naive Bayes and am greeted with the following output when predicting for a Yes or No probability

```
           No       Yes
[1,] 0.1402923 0.8597077
[2,] 0.5838934 0.4161066
[3,] 0.0272896 0.9727104
[4,] 0.953890 0.9046110
```

I want to write code that looks at this output, and when Yes is >0.5 then write "Yes", if Yes is <0.5 then write "No"

In this Case

```
[1,] Yes
[2,] No
[3,] Yes
[4,] Yes
```

Comment: You can use `ifelse` for this.

Comment: Thank you! Should have popped into my head. I did an ifelse on the second column of the matrix.